# Issue with refreshing div with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

yesterday i found code in ajax who refreshing div. Issue is:

His div refreshing making ifs in php code not working.

Can you guys tell me how to make its all working?

PHP CODE (fragment with if):

```
if($iddodawacza==$_SESSION['id'] or($_SESSION['admin']=="1")){
    echo '<a href="usuwaniepostu.php?id='.$output['id'].'">Usuń post</a>';
}
```

AJAX CODE:

```
function auto_load(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "wyswietlaniepostowstart.php",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
         $("#divzpostami").html(data);
      } 
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  auto_load(); //Call auto_load() function when DOM is Ready

});


setInterval(auto_load,2000);
```

Comment: Did you [start the session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) in the PHP file called by your AJAX?

Comment: First you'd have to explain how it's **NOT** working...

Comment: @showdev Thanks! I forgot to do this :p